# How does main.js link to Index.html in Vue-cli webpack template

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I noticed `vue-cli webpack project-name` template loads these codes.

**main.js**

```
...
new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    render: h => h(App), 
});
```

**index.html**

```
...
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>  <!-- if I change app to app1, error message states: "Cannot find element app" -->
    <script src="./dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
....
```

The two are linked together. However, how are they linked? 
It appears to be a result of **build.js** but I'm unable to understand the code as it has been compiled and minified, uglified etc...

My webpack.config.js settings is default template.

Comment: `el: "#app"` tells Vue to instantiate the Vue on the `div` with the `id` of `app`. I expect you have an error in what you posted; it's not `class="app"`, its `id="app"`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Changed that mistake. But I'm trying to write my own webpack config from scratch. However, I dont know which line of code is responsible for **el: "#app" tells Vue to instantiate the Vue on the div with the id of app** Where can I find it in the template?

Comment: It's the second line in your first block of code posted in your question. If you're trying to write your own webpack.config.js, I suggest you start with the `webpack-simple` template. It's *far* easier to get an idea of what's going on from that.

Comment: what if i wanted to change the name of **index.html** to **foo.html**
how could I make it work then?

Comment: Webpack just builds the script. You can call the HTML file whatever you want as long as it includes the built script.

Comment: I get the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` when I changed it to **foo.html**  
I also ran `npm run build` just for good measure. 

this is my output in terminal
`> test101@1.0.0 dev /home/mingsterism/Desktop/mystuff/vue/test101
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html`

Comment: if you change the id to app1 in the html file, you also have to change that in the js file, so that it works. The js file is basically compiled and bundled by webpack and is then turned to  dist/build.js

Answer (score 0):

you project used **[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)** as a module bundler - it injects app.js into index.html

to get a non-uglified bundle, edit the Webpack settings like this:

comment call plugin **uglifyjs-webpack-plugin** in **build/webpack.prod.conf.js**

before

```
...
plugins: [
// http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': env
}),
new UglifyJsPlugin({
  uglifyOptions: {
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  },
  sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
  parallel: true
}),
// extract css into its own file
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
  // set the following option to `true` if you want to extract CSS from
  // codesplit chunks into this main css file as well.
  // This will result in *all* of your app's CSS being loaded upfront.
  allChunks: false,
})
...
```

after

```
...
plugins: [
// http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': env
}),
// new UglifyJsPlugin({
//   uglifyOptions: {
//     compress: {
//       warnings: false
//     }
//   },
//   sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
//   parallel: true
// }),
// extract css into its own file
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
  // set the following option to `true` if you want to extract CSS from
  // codesplit chunks into this main css file as well.
  // This will result in *all* of your app's CSS being loaded upfront.
  allChunks: false,
}),
...
```

also if you want to change the name of index.html to foo.html of the input file you can do it here:

line 68 in **build/webpack.prod.conf.js** change to

```
template: 'foo.html',
```